# Msys компиляция svn api под windows

Tags: c, windows, api, svn

Пытаюсь скомпилировать примеры из исходного кода svn, например по пути `./tools/examples/minimal_client.c`

Пробовал с помощью `msys mingw`, путем установки `subversion` и `apr` библиотек, но безуспешно. Также пробовал с помощью CL компилятора, тоже не может dll файл принять. Может у кого нибудь был опыт компиляции программы с использованием svn api c под Windows? На старом форуме нашёл что у людей с компиляцией с помощью mingw проблем не было.

Также я пробовал скомпилировать данный пример в Linux, вообще проблем не было и все заработало.

Заранее спасибо

Comment: Ошибки в студию